# Colour of selected image in tab bar does not change in iOS 7

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I am about to submit my first app to the app store however I am having an issue that I can't figure out how to fix.

Basically, I have a UIPickerView that allows users to change the colour theme of the app. This works absolutely fine in iOS 8, however when I run the app on iOS 7, setting the colour of the selected image in the tab bar does not change.

I am using this code for changing the colour:

```
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newPinkColor()
        UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change color for selected tab by using UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal
Here is what you can do.

```
var tabIcon : UIImage = UIImage(named: "youImage.png")! //Initialize Image

var tabIcon : UITabBarItem = self.tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem //Select tab bar item 

tabIcon.selectedImage = profileIcon.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal) //It will render image to its original color
```